# "RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with" in rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I follow the [railstutorial][rails tutorial] try to setup a simple web site. 
In this page, after inserting several records to the `Users` table, I use `rails console`, trying to find out some records. But all findings fail.

Could anyone help explain why it fails? Thanks very much

```
2.0.0-p247 :064 > User.all
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "Shijie", email: "shijiexu@yahoo.com", created_at: "2016-12-24 22:36:56", updated_at: "2016-12-24 22:36:56">, #<User id: 2, name: "chen jie", email: "chejie@yahoo.com", created_at: "2016-12-24 22:37:36", updated_at: "2016-12-24 22:37:36">, #<User id: 3, name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mmm@example.com", created_at: "2016-12-25 20:56:58", updated_at: "2016-12-25 21:21:38">]> 
2.0.0-p247 :065 > User.find(name: "Shijie")
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'={:name=>"Shijie"}
    from /home/shijiex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:154:in `find'
    from (irb):65
    from /home/shijiex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/shijiex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/shijiex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/shijiex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/shijiex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'

2.0.0-p247 :066 > User.find(email: "mmm@example.com")
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'={:email=>"mmm@example.com"}
    from /home/shijiex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:154:in `find'
    from (irb):66
    from /home/shijiex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
```

The user.rb is generated.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :microposts

end
```

The rails in my version is Rails 4.2.0, though the rails in the tutorial is for v5+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` method will look for the record using the `id` column. So, in your case, it checks for the record with the `id` value of `email: "mmm@example.com"` which obviously doesn't exist.

If you want to find records by a column other than `id`, use `find_by` method and pass the `column name` and `value` as a hash.

```
User.find_by(email: "mmm@example.com")
```

For more, read the documentation of [find_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by)

Comment: Oh..I am too careless..As the example in the page uses `find_by`. Thanks